# Unity 2d, access component from code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I have components in my player object like:

[image]

How can I acces in PlayerMovement.cs that RigidBody? How can I find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Rigidbody object like

```
Rigidbody object;
```

and use

```
object = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

in `Start()` method. This works for Unity 5

Answer (score 1):

Main thing is to create a reference variable of type RigidBody like below.

`RigidBody rb;`

Then you can access the game component by using `GetComponant<RigidBody>;` function.

So now you can access to the rgid body componant as like `rb.mass = 300;`

hope this will be helpfull to you.